# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication

Tags: java, ftp

I installed FileZilla FTP server on my windows 64 bit system.
And, I am trying to connect from java application using apache commons.net 3.4 api. 
But connection is not been established. it failed saying

"org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: Connection closed without indication."

on the filezilla server client am seeing welcome message and after some time i got exception as mentioned above on console and "Disconnected" message on server console. I don't know whats going wrong here.

Comment: Use `addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)))` on your ftp client to get more details.

Comment: will you elaborate @MehrdadNurolahzade where and how can i use this function because i am having the same problem and didn't find a way

Answer (score -3):

Try using FTPSClient instead of FTPClient. if it not barely FTP and can be FTPS.